# Writing php code to creating menu in block show and alert

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, block

I have a menu in a block and this is my code in that block that is in **sidebar second**:

```
<?php
  $url=$base_url.'/drupal';
  echo
  '<ul>
  <li><a href="'.$url.'/article/1">One</a></li>
  <li> <a href="'.$url.'/article/2">Two</a></li>
  </ul>';
?>
```

it is working correctly, but return and red alert:

> Notice: Undefined variable: base_url in eval() (line 2 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to bring the variable $base_url and $base_path into the global scope. At the top of your function or template file add:

```
global $base_url;
```

and your code would be like this:

```
<?php
  global $base_url;
  $url=$base_url.'/drupal';
  echo
  '<ul>
  <li><a href="'.$url.'/article/1">One</a></li>
  <li> <a href="'.$url.'/article/2">Two</a></li>
  </ul>';
?>
```